# Integrate/Translate OCaml for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#, ocaml

I have some OCaml codes, what is the fastest way to make them run on Visual Studio? The reason is that I want to integrate the OCaml code with current code base (which is in C#). Both OCaml and C# codes are quite large.

I have some solutions:

1. Translate OCaml to one of the .net languages (like F# that have much straightforward mapping?), but this will incur great development time unless there are automatic translation tool (is there any?).
2. Calling OCaml directly by wrapping it in dll if possible (can it?).

I hope someone could provide some solutions to reduce the effort, thanks!

Comment: 2 is prorably a realistic solution, but still you need detailed knowledge of OCaml internals...

Comment: this will get tricky: F# is *almost* the same but of course the modules are quite different - also F# has overloaded operators - so you don't need `+.` and stuff (indeed those don't exist)

Comment: you could try with [this](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Compatibility) though ...

Comment: @Carsten I will give that a try, seems not bad